# Make addition to href URL string

Tags: javascript, href

I have the need to make changes to all hyperlinks on a page using Java Script. Currently the the tags are laid out in this maner

```
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/bla bla bla.aspx"
```

The change I am really struggling with (Being a absolute Noob in this field) is how i can make the following change and add in another level? Its subsite with the same structure;

```
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/+Level4/bla bla bla.aspx"
```

Sections of the URL pre and post the addition of "level 4" will remain the same. I need this change to be applied to all Hyperlinks on the page that do not have the level 4 portion already present.

Apologies for the shocking request. First time posting.

Comment: Loop all `<a>` with `if (a.href.indexOf('Level4') == -1) a.href = a.href.replace('Level3/', 'Level3/+Level4/')`

Answer (score 1):

Get all the hrefs - if the href does not have the required level 4 then add the level with a simple .replace() with the addded level - then apply as the href attribute.

Note that links 1 and 3 do not have the level 4 so will be affected by the if condition, wherease the link 2 already has it so it will not be affected.

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');

links.forEach(function(link) {
 let originalHref = link.getAttribute('href');
 if(originalHref.indexOf('+Level4') == -1) {
   link.setAttribute('href', originalHref.replace('Level3/','Level3/+Level4/'));
 }
})
```

```css
a {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/option1.aspx">Option 1</a>
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/+Level4/option2.aspx">Option 2</a>
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/option3.aspx">Option 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=> 
 a.href= a.href.replace(/(\/Level1\/Level2\/Level3)(?!\/Laravel4)/,"$1/+Laravel4"));
```

regexp explanation

- `(\/Level1\/Level2\/Level3)` find links with prefix (group $1)
- `(?!\/Laravel4)` but not containing Laravel4
- `"$1/+Laravel4"` replace matched string(group $1) with group $1 with suffix

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=> 
 a.href= a.href.replace(/(\/Level1\/Level2\/Level3)(?!\/Laravel4)/,"$1/+Laravel4"));
  
  
// INFO
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(a=>console.log(a.href));
```

```html
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/bla bla bla.aspx">link 1</a>
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/Laravel4/terefere.aspx">link 2</a>
<a href="/Level1/Level2/Level3/zzzz.aspx">link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

location.href is gave you tu url so:

```
var currentUrl= location.href;
currentUrl = currentUrl.replace("level1","level1/level2")
location.href = currentUrl;
```

I don't understand you clearly but this need to be solve your problem.